# LINQ join on two variable with different types

Tags: c#, linq

I am re-writing an Query from Progress4GL to an IQueryAble statement in LINQ and would like to join two tables on keys that have different types. In Progress4GL casting is done fairly easily but I having trouble writing the same Query in linq/C#.

Since this is a custom build Query Engine, certain functionality such as ToString() is not implemented yet for the Iqueryable conversion, and was looking for a way to get past this issue without having to implement it.

Since this is a custom Engine, supporting Linq in the format of `data.Where(x => x...).OrderBy()...` is does not work (to some extent). Below is the example I am writing:

```
var query = from invbinlotalloc in Query()
            join putline in QueryOver<Putline>()
            on invbinlotalloc.keyId equals putline.putlineId
            select invbinlotalloc;

var data = await ExecuteAsync(query, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Have you tried to cast these in the Linq query? i.e. `on ((string)invbinlotalloc.keyId) equals (string(putline.putlineId))`?

Comment: @CarloBos I ahve, `on  invbinlotalloc.keyId equals (string) putline.putlineId`, it gives me a 'cannot convert decimal to string' error

Comment: Joins in LINQ are equality joins; it doesn't make sense to join on two things of different types because a Turtle in a table of turtles is never equal to a Giraffe in a table of giraffes. What are the two types in your case, and how do you define them as being equal?

Comment: @EricLippert, you are missing the point of the points of the question. I am looking for a way to cast both to strings so they can be equated.

Comment: I'd ask whoever wrote a provider that doesn't support ToString to support ToString then. :)

Comment: Cornel, indeed the casting needs to happen instead as follows: `on invbinlotalloc.keyId?.ToString() equals putline.putlineId?.ToString()`